# Parse JSON feed from Facebook

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making a Facebook app , I have about 50 feeds from user posts from following code

```
try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me/feed?fields=likes{name},message,story,comments{from},from&limit=50');

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {

    }
    $total_posts = array();
    $posts_response = $response->getGraphEdge();
    $response_array = $posts_response->asJson();
```

i get following result in `$response_array`:

```
[{"message":"testing...","from":{"name":"Ahsan Omer","id":"1060152144046414"},"id":"1060152144046414_1060590920669203","likes":[{"name":"Ahsan Omer","id":"1060152144046414"}],"comments":[{"from":{"name":"Ahsan Omer","id":"1060152144046414"},"id":"1060590920669203_1060622407332721"}]},{"message":"testing...","from":{"name":"Ahsan Omer","id":"1060152144046414"},"id":"1060152144046414_1060530170675278","comments":[{"from":{"name":"Ahsan Omer","id":"1060152144046414"},"id":"1060530170675278_1060622427332719"}]}]
```

i want to list who has posted, who has liked and who has commented in the timeline feeds, and for that need to parse the above response, am i going about this the right way?

Comment: Of course i am only showing two feeds out of fifty, i am new to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lookup this question very easily on the web (google is your friend) but anyhow here you go with a untested, probably syntax invalid solution, but it will get you going!

The *json_decode* will decode the response to an array (your naming here is misleading due to the fact that $post_response->asJson() returns a string not an array. With *$decoded[0][message]* you will access the first array row and the column *message*.

```
$decoded = json_decode($response_array, true),
echo $decoded[0][message]
```